# Wait until user stopped typing in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program I would like to update my gui while the user is typing. For resource reasons I would however only like to do it if the user has not typed something for x milliseconds. Here is an example that works but I don't like it very much because it need two additional functions and is a little verbose.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

COLORS =["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"]

class Application(tk.Frame): 

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.counter = 0
        self.master = master
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.pack()

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.bind('<Key>',lambda event: self.handle_wait(event))


    def handle_wait(self,event):
        self.counter += 1
        counter = self.counter
        self.after(1000,lambda: self.handle_wait2(counter) )


    def handle_wait2(self,counter):
        if self.counter == counter:
            self.change_color()

    def change_color(self):
        random_color = random.choice(COLORS)
        self.entry.config(background=random_color)

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You might be able to use the optional validation features of an `Entry` widget to record the time the last keystroke was entered, and then check that value in an `after()` callback function. There's details on `Entry` widget validation [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use `after` to schedule the function to run after the user stops typing. Then, all you need to do is restart the job each time you get a button click.

First, create a variable to store an id that represents the future function call. You can also throw away `self.counter` as it's not needed.

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    self._after_id = None
    ...
```

Next, remove lambda in your binding. It's pointless and makes the code more complex than it needs to be:

```
self.entry.bind('<Key>',self.handle_wait)
```

Finally, change your `handle_wait` function to look like this:

```
def handle_wait(self, event):
    # cancel the old job
    if self._after_id is not None:
        self.after_cancel(self._after_id)

    # create a new job
    self.after(1000, self.change_color)
```

Here's a complete example based on your code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

COLORS =["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"]

class Application(tk.Frame): 

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.pack()

        self._after_id = None
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.bind('<Key>',self.handle_wait)

    def handle_wait(self,event):
        # cancel the old job
        if self._after_id is not None:
            self.after_cancel(self._after_id)

        # create a new job
        self._after_id = self.after(1000, self.change_color)

    def change_color(self):
        random_color = random.choice(COLORS)
        self.entry.config(background=random_color)

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. The solution with the cancel function is very elegant and I had no idea it existed. Very useful

Comment: Hi, thanks for this useful code Bryan. I'm trying to do the same without a class. You have `after(1000, self.change_color)` bound to `.self` When I try bind it to the entry widget or root, it freezes 1000 for each `<key>` ... is it necessary to bind this to a frame widget as you have or whats the best way to resolve this?

Comment: @Rhys: I don't quite understand your terminology. The `after` command must be given a reference to a function that is to be called. It doesn't matter if that function is part of a class or not. You never bind it to an entry widget or any other widget -- you bind it to a function.

Comment: @Bryan: replacing `.self` with `tk.Frame()` solved this. `tk.Frame().after(1000, self.change_color)` ... thanks again Bryan!

Comment: @Rhys: ah, so that's what you mean by "bind". Yes, `after` is a method common to all widgets.